# And the Sultans played creole?

Tags: meaning, lyrics

Here are some lyrics from the great classic Sultans of Swing:

```
Then a crowd a young boys they're a foolin' around in the corner
Drunk and dressed in their best brown baggies and their platform soles
They don't give a damn about any trumpet playin' band
It ain't what they call Rock and Roll
And the Sultans
Yeah, the Sultans, they play Creole
```

What does **creole** mean in this case? I have difficulty finding a definition that fits; I get something about ethnic / minorities/ some sauce.

I guess that what the song tries to communicate here is that the great music played by the sultans is not recognized by the patrons, so either the sultans changed their music to a more well received genre which is implied a pity by dire straits, or on the other hand creole is something great that is re-emphasized.

Comment: Here's an article about the writing of the Dire Straits song which discusses its lyrics (inspired by seeing a terrible jazz band), although it doesn't mention creole. https://www.loudersound.com/features/the-story-behind-the-song-dire-straits-sultans-of-swing

Comment: [Creole music](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creole_music) has it's own Wikipedia page. This is General Reference, to the extent that it's not simply Off Topic "song lyrics interpretation".

Answer (score 4):

It probably refers to ***Creole music***, a folk kind of music in Louisiana.

> The term "Creole music" is used to describe both ***the early folk or roots music traditions of French and Metis rural Creoles of South Louisiana and the later more contemporary genre called Zydeco***. It was often simply called French music or La La. It was sung in French patois by Creoles. *This early American roots music evolved in the 1930s into a richer sound accompanied by more instruments*. Creole pioneer Amede Ardoin is said to be the first Creole to record this indigenous music.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_of_Louisiana))

[image]

Here's what it looks and sounds like [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kFo5aYJI2U).

Comment: I am convinced.